# Pirkei drabbi Eliezer questions

Tags: women, midrash, curse, agada-stories-legends

Pirkay D'rabbi Eliyeser [14.5](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.14.5)

Hashem gave the woman nine curses and death:

1. The afflictions of child birth
2. The afflictions of blood of virginity
3. The affliction of pregnancy
4. The affliction of bringing up children
5. Her head is covered like a mourner,
6. and she does not shave it except on account of immorality.
7. Her ear is pierced like (the ears of) perpetual slaves.
8. Like a hand-maid (slave) she waits upon her husband.
9. She is not believed as a witness.

And after all these, death.

There would seem to be several problems with this.

1. Was there originally no way of having children?
2. Same as #1.
3. Like the first two, this only applies if the woman is married, and has children.
4. Does this mean that their hair is long? That doesn't seem like a con. And if it means that they must cover their hair then A- again, only when married and B- the Terumat Hadeshen holds - I believe - that women covering their hair is drabbanun, and therefore not really from Hashem.
5. Aren't there chassidish women who shave their heads? Also, is it asur drabbanun, Das Yehudit, or nothing which says they must not shave their heads? Unless it's דאורייתא it's again not from Hashem
6. That's voluntary. They like earrings. Exactly how is that a curse?
7. Those responsibilities - as far as I know - are mostly drabbanun. Again not from Hashem.

Comment: Number 1 *afflictions of childbirth* means that before, she could give birth in the same way but it would not hurt and it would not be fatal.

Comment: @sabbahillel just about to post that. Orion, 3 is likely the same answer as well - think of how much easier pregnancy could possibly be.  Re: 4 - PDRE is assuming that in general women will be getting married and raising children, and I'm not sure what you mean about a chiyuv being derabanan? I would also suggest looking at a Peirush on it if you can find one, but I'll take a look at the rest if/when I have time.  I'm especially bothered by 7, unless it is specifically referring to Chava. I also am troubled by 5/6.

Comment: רבות מחשבות Thanks number 3s thing about drabbanun was a mistake. I've edited out.

Comment: This seems to be awfully broad. Maybe you should split this into separate questions?

Comment: I don't really see it as broad though I can understand that each one of these princely has its own complicated answer. I'll give it a day or so and if there aren't any answers I'll split it into separate questions.